# Explore.exe Address Bar "Shell:" Command in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-shell, sendto

With Windows 7 was just trying to navigate to

```
c:\users\scott.cate\sendto
```

to modify the [send to] context menu and I was getting access denied. With a little search engine work I found this trick.

Open Windows Explorer (Win+E Shortcut) and type

```
Shell:sendto
```

into the addres bar and press enter. Windows Explorer opens up to

```
C:\Users\scott.cate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

which is what I was really looking for.

So my question is (which I couldn't find in the search engines) ...

Does anyone know of a master list of these "Shell:" shortcut commands and/or some documentation for Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bunch of them, try these ones for Vista:

http://www.nerdgrind.com/vista-shell-commands-list-and-how-to-use-them/

Answer (score 1):

The other link is now broken. Here's an explanation and comprehensive list for Windows 7:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2013/02/13/windows-shell-commands.aspx

And here's the list, for posterity:

AddNewProgramsFolder

Administrative Tools

AppData

AppUpdatesFolder

Cache

CD Burning

ChangeRemoveProgramsFolder

Common Administrative Tools

Common AppData

Common Desktop

Common Documents

Common Programs

Common Start Menu

Common Startup

Common Templates

CommonDownloads

CommonMusic

CommonPictures

CommonRingtones

CommonVideo

ConflictFolder

ConnectionsFolder

Contacts

ControlPanelFolder

Cookies

CredentialManager

CryptoKeys

CSCFolder

Default Gadgets

Desktop

Device Metadata Store

DocumentsLibrary

Downloads

DpapiKeys

Favorites

Fonts

Gadgets

Games

GameTasks

History

HomeGroupFolder

ImplicitAppShortcuts

InternetFolder

Libraries

Links

Local AppData

LocalAppDataLow

LocalizedResourcesDir

MAPIFolder

MusicLibrary

My Music

My Pictures

My Video

MyComputerFolder

NetHood

NetworkPlacesFolder

OEM Links

Original Images

Personal

PhotoAlbums
 PicturesLibrary
 Playlists
 PrintersFolder
 PrintHood
 Profile
 ProgramFiles
 ProgramFilesCommon
 ProgramFilesCommonX64
 ProgramFilesCommonX86
 ProgramFilesX64
 ProgramFilesX86
 Programs
 Public
 PublicGameTasks
 PublicLibraries
 Quick Launch
 Recent
 RecordedTVLibrary
 RecycleBinFolder
 ResourceDir
 Ringtones
 SampleMusic
 SamplePictures
 SamplePlaylists
 SampleVideos
 SavedGames
 Searches
 SearchHomeFolder
 SendTo
 Start Menu
 Startup
 SyncCenterFolder
 SyncResultsFolder
 SyncSetupFolder
 System
 SystemCertificates
 SystemX86
 Templates
 User Pinned
 UserProfiles
 UserProgramFiles
 UserProgramFilesCommon
 UsersFilesFolder
 UsersLibrariesFolder
 VideosLibrary
 Virtual Machines
 Windows